# no mapping found for /info Spring 4 websockets

Tags: spring, spring-4, spring-websocket

In spring controllers if I use `@MessageMapping` it is working, but if I changed to `@Requestmapping(value=="",method=RequestMethod.POST)` and try to use `SimpMessagingTemplate` to send the messages to client then it is unable to connect, it is showing error in

```
connecting to websockets /info request mapping not found
```

Comment: Could explain a bit more what you're trying to achieve? What request is the browser sending? What do you expect to happen? Could you show extensive code examples?

Answer (score 0):

I recognize /info from SockJS. Are you using it on the backend?

In my configuration, I have a STOMP endpoint at /stomp and use SockJS on the client side to do the WebSocket connection. SockJS makes a request to /stomp/info first to figure out what kind of connection to make.